# How does bone marrow acts like a valve?

Tags: physiology, bone-biology, lymphatic-system

[Wikipedia says:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_marrow)

> Furthermore, bone marrow performs a **valve-like** function to prevent the backflow of lymphatic fluid in the lymphatic system.

How can bone marrow act like a valve eventhough they [neither](https://training.seer.cancer.gov/anatomy/lymphatic/components/) have lymphvesseles nor contracting property?

Comment: Could you explain why you think bone marrow should not have a lymphatic system?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I really didn't understand how is your question related to my question. My question is how does bone marrow acts like a valve to prevent back flow of lymph even though it does not have any lymph vessels, I know muscles can act like a valve by contracting , but not about bone marrow which neither has ability to contract nor have any lymph vessels. Hope you understand my question, Thanks.

Comment: I think your question is predicated on at least one false statement. What if marrow does have a lymphatic system?

Comment: Okay then also how can it act like a valve?

Comment: Hey, you didn't even react to the preceding comment. Do some reading! Show where you're hung up.

Comment: My top priority was to know the mechanism behind it, If we even consider that bone marrow has lymphatics then also it doesn't mean that it can prevent back flow in lymphatics since they don't have any contractile property. Also many sites say that bone marrow doesn't have lymphatics, What I have learned is that bone marrow produces lymphocytes which enter into circulation by diapedesis into sinusoids. So, in this sense it makes bone marrow a lymphoid organ but I still don't understand how direcly(or indirectly ) does it prevent back flow of lymph. Thanks, hope you understand my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, though bone marrow is not considered a part of lymphatic system because it is not connected to lymph vessels, yet it is the site of production of both B- and T-lymphocytes and is thus considered as primary lymphoid organ<sup>[1](https://www.britannica.com/science/lymphatic-system)</sup>. So, it is closely related to lymphatic system.

On doing some research, I can conclude that bone marrow itself actually does not perform the role of a valve. It is the lymph vessels itself which perform the valve-like function. See this<sup>[2](http://www.encyclopedia.com/medicine/news-wires-white-papers-and-books/lymphatic-system)</sup>:

> As lymph capillaries carry lymph away from the tissue spaces, they merge to form larger and larger vessels. These larger lymph vessels resemble veins, but their walls are thinner and they have more one-way valves to prevent lymph from flowing backward. Whereas the cardiovascular system has a pump (the heart) to move fluid (blood) through the system, the lymphatic system does not. It relies on the contraction of muscles to move lymph throughout the body. The larger lymph vessels have a layer of smooth muscle in their walls that contracts rhythmically to "pump" lymph along. The contraction of skeletal muscles, brought about by simple body movement, and the mechanics of breathing also help to move lymph on its way.

[image: lymphatic system]

So, I'd consider that paragraph as one of the few places where Wikipedia has given incorrect fact.

Comment: I highly doubt that it could be wrong fact, anyway thanks for efforts.

Comment: As long as they _mean_ bone marrow there, and there are no back ups, and counterexamples already present, I would consider it as incorrect.